# EF (6.1.3) context table record count is 0 after multiple inserts

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to do a bulk insert from an XML file (parsed and analyzed).  I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 in VB.net.

The processing of the XML file (not saving) took about 6.5 minutes to run.  By Googling I found

```
ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = False
```

which brought the processing time down to 15 seconds!  Hooray!

The problem is, when I get to `ctx.SaveChanges()` it takes 20+ minutes to write the data to the database!  It is just flooding the SQL server with single Insert statements.  In an effort to make this more efficient, I want to do a BulkInsert.  I came across a couple different options including SQLBulkCopy and what I am currently using EFUtilities.  My code is as follows:

```
        Using ctx As New MyContext()

            For Each dp As XElement In de.Elements

                Party = New DistinctParty()
                With Party
                    .Comment = dp.<d:Comment>.Value
                    .ListID = ListType
                End With

                ctx.DistinctParties.Add(Party)

                AddAliases(dp.<d:Profile>.<d:Identity>.FirstOrDefault(), ctx)
                AddFeatures(dp.<d:Profile>.<d:Feature>, ctx)

            Next

            ' Save the items

            Dim DPs As List(Of Integer)
            DPs = ctx.DistinctParties.Where(Function(x) x.ListID = ListType).Select(Function(x) x.DistinctPartyID).ToList

            EFBatchOperation.For(ctx, ctx.DistinctParties).InsertAll(ctx.DistinctParties.Where(Function(x) x.ListID = ListType))
            EFBatchOperation.For(ctx, ctx.DistinctPartyAliases).InsertAll(ctx.DistinctPartyAliases.Where(Function(x) DPs.Contains(x.DistinctPartyID)))
            EFBatchOperation.For(ctx, ctx.DistinctPartyFeatures).InsertAll(ctx.DistinctPartyFeatures.Where(Function(x) DPs.Contains(x.DistinctPartyID)))

            'ctx.SaveChanges()

        End Using
```

`ctx.SaveChanges()` works fine with this. It just takes 20 minutes.
Problem is, `DPs.Count` is 0!  If I had old record in the database before I delete them earlier in the code, DPs is the count of the data that WAS in the database.

QUESTION: Why is DPs.Count = 0 when there is really data in the context for the 3 different tables?

RELATED QUESTION: Is this the correct way to do the bulk insert?

Comment: I think I can create 3 lists (one for each table) that are not part of the context, then add them that way.  But shouldn't the code above be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QUESTION**: Why is DPs.Count = 0 when there is really data in the context for the 3 different tables?

When you use LINQ Queryable, the results (count, first, etc.) are taken from what's currently in the database and doesn't care about what's in context/change tracker which is similar to a list of "pending" entities waiting to be committed/saved to the database.

So this is why the count equal 0 if the database has 0 records even if you are adding thousands of entities in the context (which have not been saved yet)

**RELATED QUESTION**: Is this the correct way to do the bulk insert?

There are three main libraries supporting Bulk Insert, you can read my [Bulk Insert Library Reviews & Comparisons](http://entityframework.net/bulk-insert)

In short, I recommend [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/) over other libraries since it's the only one really supported and has way more flexibility than other libraries: Bulk Insert, Update, Delete, Merge and BulkSaveChanges.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)